# Serial ports writing/reading in linux

Tags: java, c++, linux, serial-port, raspbian

I need to implement communication between two devices through serial ports on Raspberry Pi (with last Raspbian on board). Both uses CP2102 controller and connected to the Pi.

[image: Data flow]

**Terminal:**

```
pi@pi ~ $ ls -l /dev/serial/by-id
total 0
Silicon_Labs_CP2102_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0001-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB2

pi@pi ~ $ ls -l /dev/serial/by-path
total 0
platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.2.1:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB1
platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.2.4:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB2
platform-bcm2708_usb-usb-0:1.3:1.0-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
```

Normally when I send command to SERIAL A, Device A replies through SERIAL A and sends data through SERIAL B. After that I need to retranslate this data to Device B (SERIAL C) and receive answer from SERIAL C.

The problem is that SERIAL A reply appears on SERIAL B and SERIAL B data appears on SERIAL A.

I've tried different languages and serial libraries but the result is the same. So the questions are: why is it happening when using Raspberry Pi? How can I implement this functionality on Raspberry Pi?

P.S. Both devices are working properly. My C# code works perfect. I used System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class for that implementation and it looks like Pi4J and RXTX solutions.

P.P.S. Some code that I tried to use on RPi:

**[Serial](http://wjwwood.io/serial/), C++:** (very bad piece of code)

```
Serial port("/dev/ttyUSB2", 115200U);
Serial port1("/dev/ttyUSB1", 115200U);
port1.setTimeout(Timeout::max(), 250, 0, 250, 0);
port.setTimeout(Timeout::max(), 250, 0, 250, 0);

cout << "Is the serial port open?";
if (port1.isOpen()) {
    cout << " Yes." << endl;
    uint8_t data[2] = { 0xAA, 0x00 };
    port1.write(data, 2);
    data[1] = 0xFF;
    sleep(1);
    port1.write(data, 2);
    while (port.available() < 7);
    int av = port.available();
    string ss;
    port.read(ss, av);
    for (int i = 0; i < av; i++){
        cout << (uint)ss.at(i) << " ";
    }
    cout << "av: " + (uint)av << endl;
}
```

**RXTX, Java:**

```
    public class Bridge_rxtx {
        public static final int baudrate = 115200;

        protected SerialPort spDevB_Data;
        SerialReader devB_DataListener;

        protected SerialPort spDevA_Data;
        SerialReader DevA_DataListener;

        protected SerialPort spDevA_Control;
        SerialPortEventListener DevA_ControlListener;

        public Bridge_rxtx(String comDevB_Data, String comDevA_Data, String comDevA_Control) {
            try {
            spDevB_Data = setupPort(comDevB_Data);
            spDevA_Data = setupPort(comDevA_Data);
            spDevA_Control = setupPort(comDevA_Control);
            } catch (Exception ignored){
                ignored.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                devB_DataListener = new SerialReader(spDevB_Data.getInputStream(), spDevA_Data.getOutputStream(), "B-A");
                DevA_DataListener = new SerialReader(spDevA_Data.getInputStream(), spDevB_Data.getOutputStream(), "A-B");
                DevA_ControlListener = new SerialPortEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                    }
                };

            spDevB_Data.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
            spDevA_Data.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
            spDevA_Control.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Bridge_rxtx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

        public void launchBridge(){
            System.out.println("Starting...");
            try {
                spDevA_Control.getOutputStream().write(new byte[] {(byte)0xAA, (byte) 0x00}, 0, 2);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Bridge_rxtx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Bridge_rxtx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                spDevA_Control.getOutputStream().write(new byte[] {(byte)0xAA, (byte) 0xFF}, 0, 2);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Bridge_rxtx.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("Started");
        }

        SerialPort setupPort(String portName) throws Exception {
            SerialPort serialPort = null;
            CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
            if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
                System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
            } else {
                CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(), 2000);
                if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) {
                    serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(baudrate, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this code.");
                }
            }
            return serialPort;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Bridge_rxtx bridge = new Bridge_rxtx("/dev/ttyUSB0", "/dev/ttyUSB2", "/dev/ttyUSB1");
            bridge.launchBridge();
        }
    }
```

**Pi4J, Java:**

```
public class Bridge {
    public static Bridge instance;

    public static final int baudrate = 115200;

    protected Serial spDevB_Data;
    SerialDataListener devB_DataListener;

    protected Serial spDevA_Data;
    SerialDataListener devA_DataListener;

    protected Serial spDevA_Control;
    SerialDataListener devA_ControlListener;

    private Bridge() {

    }
    public Bridge(String comDevB_Data, String comDevA_Data, String comDevA_Control) {
        instance = this;

        devA_ControlListener = new SerialDataListener() {
        //SerialDataEvent in Pi4J doesn't support binary
        //data by default. I implemented this myself.
            public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event) {
                System.out.println(bytesToHex(toPrimitives(event.getBinaryData())));
            }

        };
        devB_DataListener = new SerialDataListener() {
            public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event) {
                byte[] data = toPrimitives(event.getBinaryData());
                instance.spDevA_Data.write(data);
                System.out.println("B -> A: " + bytesToHex(data));
            }

        };
        devA_DataListener = new SerialDataListener() {
            public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event) {
                byte[] data = toPrimitives(event.getBinaryData());
                instance.spDevB_Data.write(data);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(15);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Bridge.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                System.out.println("B <- A: " + bytesToHex(data));
            }

        };

        spDevB_Data = SerialFactory.createInstance();
        spDevB_Data.addListener(devB_DataListener);

        spDevA_Data = SerialFactory.createInstance();
        spDevA_Data.addListener(devA_ControlListener);

        spDevA_Control = SerialFactory.createInstance();
        spDevA_Control.addListener(devA_DataListener);


        spDevB_Data.setMonitorInterval(40);
        spDevA_Data.setMonitorInterval(80);
        spDevA_Control.setMonitorInterval(25);

        spDevB_Data.open(comDevB_Data, baudrate);

        spDevA_Data.open(comDevA_Data, baudrate);
        spDevA_Control.open(comDevA_Control, baudrate);

    }

    public void SetupBridge() {
        spDevA_Control.write(new byte[]{(byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0x00});
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Bridge.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        spDevA_Control.write(new byte[]{(byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xFF});
    }
}
```

Comment: "The problem is that SERIAL A reply appears on SERIAL B and SERIAL B data appears on SERIAL A" <-- probably a stupid question (I have no clue about the hardware layout) but... Is the wiring OK?

Comment: A simple remedy might be to simply prefix an identifier to the data sent through each of the ports. Then comes in the algorithm to figure out whether to accept the reply or negate it.

Comment: RPi has two USB ports. Each device connected to one of them. So the wiring is OK :)

Comment: Prefix complicates the system so it's acceptable if it's the only way to get this working.

Comment: OK, I still haven't got a clue as to the problem at hand, but if you use a JDK 7+, can you at least make use of try-with-resources in the Java code?

Comment: I didn't know about this feature. Thanks for remark, I will use it.

Comment: You wrote *"Normally when I send command..."* that you expect certain responses, and *"I've tried different languages and serial libraries but the result is"* not what you expect.  So under what circumstances did you actually get the *"normal"* responses?  Or was that just a figure of speech to paraphrase some manual?

Comment: @sawdust , my mistake. In the P.S. section I wrote that it works when using C# (Windows). Moreover, after 0xAA, 0xFF command device should reply with it's ID in well-known format.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough reputation to comment:
My educated guess would be that it has something to do with how Linux enumerates hardware. I think it's possible that your USB devices will have another serial-path depending on the used distro, and order of connecting them.

Are you sure that you use the same USB port every time? And that the correct USB port is mapped to /dev/tty?

You can force a HID to always have the same name by making sure you have a udev rule for it. Some info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66901/how-to-bind-usb-device-under-a-static-name)

Comment: I'm sure the problem has nothing in common with device enumeration in Linux. Actually I've dropped the idea of connecting both devices to the Pi because it's no longer relevant. Nevertheless thanks for reply.

Comment: you are welcome; I was just triggered by a comment that it was running fine with C# on windows. I don't know what implemtation of C# you are running on the Raspberry.